# Total points in Google Forms

Tags: google-forms

Is there a way to get Google Forms to show the total score after a quiz?  I know there is an option to show total score and the results/answers for each question but I don't want this last part. I want my users to have another go at the quiz to see if they can figure out what they got wrong and try to get a perfect score.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the answer is no. One would have to look into making their quiz in google sites with some programming.